# Why MYSQL doesn't use the index for the same query if I query more columns?

Tags: mysql, database, primary-key

I have the following table:

```
create table stuff (
       id mediumint unsigned not null auto_increment primary key,
       title varchar(150) not null,
       link varchar(250) not null,
       time timestamp default current_timestamp not null,
       content varchar(1500)
);
```

If I EXPLAIN the query

```
select id from stuff order by id;
```

then it says it uses they primary key as an index for ordering the results. But with this query:

```
select id,title from stuff order by id;
```

EXPLAIN says no possible keys and it resorts to filesort.

Why is that? Isn't the data of a certain row stored together in the database? If it can order the results using the index when I'm querying only the id then why adding an other column to the query makes a difference? The primary key identifies the row already, so I think it should use the primary key for ordering in the second case too.

Can you explain why this is not the case?

Comment: I am not sure about the answer, but here is how it works .. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/order-by-optimization.html

Comment: None of the cases it lists where the index cannot be used seem to apply here.

Comment: If you like to learn more about these things without diving too deep, you might be interested my [SQL Indexing Tutorial (covers MySQL)](http://use-the-index-luke.com/) for developers. Your particular question is answered in the first chapter - [Anatomy of an Index](http://use-the-index-luke.com/de/sql/anatomy).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, because it is more performant in this query: you need to read full index and after that iteratively read row by row from data. This is extremely unefficient. Instead of this mysql just prefers to read the data right from the data file.

Also, what kind of storage engine do you use? Seems like mysam.

For this case innodb would be more efficient, since it uses clustered indexes over primary key (which is monotonously growing in your case).

Comment: Okay, but why doesn't it use the index to return the rows in order after it retrieved the data from the data file? Read the data into memory and then return the rows iteratively by using the index. Using an already sorted index file to do it would be faster than filesorting all the rows, wouldn't it?

Comment: @Tom: if it was - mysql would do that ;-) Since it doesn't - it is not faster. How many rows do you have? For amount < about 10k the sorting using filesort is performed terribly fast. And index for such kind of query can be useless.

Comment: It's not a large table, so it's not a performance issue yet. Do you say if the table grows over, say, 100k rows then mysql will use the index file? Does the result of explain depend on the size of table?

Comment: @Tom: It might use the index when table become bigger. And the execution plan depends on a lot of parameters like: size of block, average size of row/index item, index cardinality, amount of rows, percent of fetched rows, etc etc. As of your query (when you select everything from the table) I'm not sure that mysql ever will use PK for resolve order, but the best case when I think it could is: innodb as storage engine + a lot of rows.

Comment: The speed is no issue yet I just wanted to know the reasons of it's not using the index. As for the selecting all rows question: I tried adding limit and offset, but it made no difference. Thanks for the innodb suggestion. I'll use it when the table will grow very large.

Comment: @Tom: as far as I know limit and offset are applied after optimizer have built the execution plan, so they do not affect on it. For now I haven't any mysql server near and cannot reproduce the issue.